# Error running a geoprocess for all layers in separate maps ArcGIS Pro

Tags: python, linear-referencing, arctoolbox

Trying to create a toolbox that will run locate features along routes for all layers in two separate Maps in ArcGIS Pro.  Code snippet is below.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
myMap = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
myMap1 = aprx.listMaps("Map")[1]

out_table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_routes = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

for lyr in myMap.listLayers():
    arcpy.lr.LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes(lyr, in_routes, "RouteId", "0 Feet", out_table, "RouteId Line FMEAS TMEAS", "FIRST", "DISTANCE", "ZERO", "FIELDS", "M_DIRECTON")

for lyr in myMap1.listLayers():
    arcpy.lr.LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes(lyr, in_routes, "RouteId", "0 Feet", out_table, "RouteId Point FMEAS", "FIRST", "DISTANCE", "ZERO", "FIELDS", "M_DIRECTON")
```

Returns an

```
IndexErrror: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to indicate *where* the error occurs

Comment: `aprx.listMaps("Map")` returns either 0 or 1 items but you're trying to access the first and second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless both of your maps are named "Map", then `aprx.listMaps("Map")[index]` won't work.

Read the [doc](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm) - The `listMaps` method optionally expects a wildcard string, so `"Map"` will only match maps called "Map" exactly.

Try something like:

```py
# Assumes exactly 2 maps in aprx
map1, map2 = aprx.listMaps()  

# or

# Assumes first 2 maps in aprx are the ones
maps = aprx.listMaps() 
map1 = maps[0]
map2 = maps[1]


# or  

# Assumes only 2 maps in aprx called Map*, e.g Map and Map2
map1, map2 = aprx.listMaps("Map*")
```